# C# How do use one image as a cookie cutter for removing part of another image

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

I have an image with a decent portion of it transparent. It's the result of a green screen process. I need to overlay a filter on top of the image without laying on top of the transparent portions. You could think of it like using the base image as a cookie cutter to remove a matching shape from the filter image so I can merge them.

I've tried combing through AForge but I don't see anything helpful and google is returning all sorts of garbage. If anyone has any suggestions on where to start or alternate methods I would appreciate it.

Comment: What in-memory format is your image in? Does it have an alpha channel? If so, you could for instance do a variation of: `DestRGBA = SourceRGBA + OverlayRGBA * SourceA` but we won't be able to help without further details.

Comment: Yes. Would need more information. What kind of filter would you need applied? C#, natively would support applying changes within a Region

Comment: The incoming image is a bitmap in a memory stream. The filter is just a .png made up of alternating black, grey and white horizontal bars with varying levels of alpha. 

I have two versions of green screen software one that would spit out the file with alpha and one that would cut it out with no alpha. I can use whichever is better.

Thanks for the replies :)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution that works for me but may not answer the question directly, as I asked it. Someone else may find this useful though.

I Iterated through image I wanted to cut out. At each pixel position I would use that same position to check the "cookie cutter" image and if the Alpha channel was 0, I would then set the pixel value on the base image to 0. I was basically setting everything other than the cookie cutter shape to transparent.

A caveat is this only works if the image are the exact same size and you can't easily change the location of the where you want the cutout.